# Client wont recognize constructor functions of CollectionDataContract in wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

i have created a service in wcf with a model, in which i have created a list as followed:

```
    [CollectionDataContract]
    public class UserList : List<User>
    {
        public UserList() { }
        public UserList(IEnumerable<User> list) : base(list) { }
        public UserList(IEnumerable<BaseEntity> list) : base(list.Cast<User>().ToList()) { }
    }
```

on the client side i created the following code:

```
        User curruser;
        public UserNav(User user)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<User> users = new List<User>();
            users.Add(curruser);
            IEnumerable<User> users1 = users;
            UserList ulist = new UserList(users1);
            
        }
```

but when creating the UserList i get the following error message:
`UserList does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments.`

this really confuses me as i have created a constructor that takes an argument in UserList

i have tried changing the service reference settings as followed: [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd6W3.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, when I copy your code into a console app it compiles and runs without any exceptions, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/2kvzIr.  It's not even clear from your question whether the error you describe is a compiler error or a runtime exception, or whether it occurs on the client side or server side.  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] as suggested by [ask].

Comment: That being said, there is one problem I noticed with your code: in your `UserNav` you do not add the incoming `User user` to the `ulist` or set `curruser = user`.  As such `ulist` contains an null entry after the constructor exits.  Setting `curruser = user;` before constructing the list seems like it would be correct, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/js7Zcq.

Comment: Is the problem that, when you generate a client from the WSDL for your WCF service, the `UserList` generated on the client side does not have the `public UserList(IEnumerable<User> list) : base(list) { }` constructor?  If so, for your [mcve] please share the (possibly simplified) server-side versions of `UserList`, `User` and `BaseEntity` as well as the equivalent classes generated on the client side.  Thanks!